# Push not working for sub-sub-array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537ba668a9df7408986afc05"),
    "AppName" : "My App",
    "AppId" : "123",
    "AppGreetingText" : "Thank you!",
    "AppGreetingImageUrl" : "http://www.cute-wallpaper.com/backgrounds/rainbow/colorful_rainbow_party.jpg",
    "DateCreated" : ISODate("2014-05-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "AppUsers" : [ 
        {
            "uId" : 1
            "Token" : "123",
            "UserName" : "Donna Amhccijhfidb Sidhuwitz",
            "ProfileImageUrl" : "1.png",
            "Email" : "bla@bla.net",
            "BookIds" : []
        }
```

I want to push a new string in to `PostIds`.

```
var query = Query.And(
                Query<App>.EQ(a => a.Id, entity.Id),
                Query<AppUser>.EQ(u => u.uId, UserId)
                );

            var updateResult = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Update(
                query,
                Update<AppUser>.Push(au => au.BookIds, bookId),

                new MongoUpdateOptions()
                {
                    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged,
                });
```

I have done similar thing with sub arrays, but this does not seem to work the same for sub-sub arrays and I can't figure out why. bookIds is a `List<string>` in the POCO, if that's relevant.

**Edit:** Henk - You are right. "this does not seem to work" meaning that I expect the new string to be pushed in to the array, but the actual result is that it is not pushed in to the array and the array remain empty, like the one in the sample document. I was looking through the result and I could not find any errors in the `WriteConcernResult`. I got an `"ok" : 1` response, but with zero rows affected.

Comment: _"this does not seem to work"_ is not much of a problem description. Post errormessages and actual vs expected outcomes.

Comment: you are trying to update the matched AppUsers element of the array?  You need to use the positional operator.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/  or something like Update.Push("AppUsers.$.BookIds",bookId)

Comment: As I remember this is not supported currently. Use the non-generic version instead. `Update.Push("AppUser.BookIds", bookId)`. Can't find the related document right now. Still searching...

Comment: @yaoxing - That might be the case, but I am using version 1.9.1 and when I try to use the non-generic version I get a compiler error: `Could not choose method from method group.` Documentation for the `C#` driver doesn`t currently get this far and I am having trouble finding an example.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Your right, I updated the question with more information. Hope it's better now. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I don't have driver 1.9 here. Do you have the `public static UpdateBuilder Push(string name, BsonValue value)` signature in driver 1.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been going about this all wrong. I don't know what I was thinking, but the way I was writing the query was not giving me access to the object I needed. I wanted to access a sub-document and all I can access right out of the collection object is an entity of type `App`, no matter what kind of query I write. Any query on this collection can only return a complete `App` type document.

What I needed to do is locate the specific sub-document in the single `App` document I found. The code I ended up using is:

```
var query = Query<App>.EQ(a => a.Id, entity.Id);
var itemIndex = entity.AppUsers.FindIndex(u => u.Id == userId);
var updateResult = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Update(
                   query,
                   Update<App>.Push(a => a.AppUsers[itemIndex].BookIds, bookId),

                   new MongoUpdateOptions()
                   {
                       WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Acknowledged,
                   });
```

Now everything seems very logical, but as they say "hindsight is always 20/20". Hope this can help other people taking the first step with the C# driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the generic API works this way. But with MongoDB C# Driver 1.8 I would expect the following code to work:

```
var query = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("_id", entity.Id),
    Query.EQ("AppUsers.uId", UserId)
);
var update = Update.Push("AppUsers.$.BookIds", bookId);
var updateResult = this.MongoConnectionHandler.MongoCollection.Update(
    query, update);
```

I ignored the `WriteConcern` part because I think `Acknowledged` is the default setting.

Comment: Thank you. You got me heading in the right direction. Too bad I had to use non-generic code samples and "raw" `MongoDB` queries to find my way around the strongly-typed C# driver. Maybe it's just me and everyone else is getting along just fine :)